# How would I select a single table checkbox with Xpath using unique values in the table?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, html-table

Let's say I'm working with a webpage table element with an HTML tree like this:

```html
<table>
<tr row-number="1">
<td value="0-SELECTABLE_CHECKBOX-0">
<lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox lightning-datatable_table="">
<span class="slds-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>
<span class="slds-checkbox_faux">
</span>
<span>Select Item 1</span>
</label>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox>
</td>
<th label="Product Company">
<lightning-primitive-cell-factory label="Product Company">
<span>
<div>
<lightning-base-formatted-text>Company 1</lightning-base-formatted-text>
</div>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
</th>
<td label="Product Name">
<lightning-primitive-cell-factory label="Product Name">
<span>
<div>
<lightning-base-formatted-text>Product type 1</lightning-base-formatted-text>
</div>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
</td>
</tr>
<tr row-number="2">
<td value="0-SELECTABLE_CHECKBOX-0">
<lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox lightning-datatable_table="">
<span class="slds-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>
<span class="slds-checkbox_faux">
</span>
<span>Select Item 2</span>
</label>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox>
</td>
<th label="Product Company">
<lightning-primitive-cell-factory label="Product Company">
<span>
<div>
<lightning-base-formatted-text>Company 2</lightning-base-formatted-text>
</div>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
</th>
<td label="Product Name">
<lightning-primitive-cell-factory label="Product Name">
<span>
<div>
<lightning-base-formatted-text>Product type 2</lightning-base-formatted-text>
</div>
</span>
</lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to use Xpath to select a single unique checkbox input element in the table, but I can only use the Company and Product values listed in the table itself, so I cannot select by row number. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

@Matt M, for python and Selenium, you can do as given below. You can replace the url given in the code. It will select the row based on company name provided in variable `company`. Same can be done for the product name:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=s)
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5555/dropdown.html")
allRows = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
company = "Company 2"

for row in allRows:
    if company in row.text:
        row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that using xpath, you need to use [the document.evaluate() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) which supports xpath. You then need to form an xpath expression.

In this case it could be (among some other options)

```
//table//tr[.//.="Company 2"][.//.="Product type 1"]//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

which could be roughly translated into English as

> in the table, find a `<tr>` which has, among its children, a text
> element equal to "Company 2" (or whatever) and another one equal to
> "Product type 1" (again, or whatever); once you find it, look for
> another `<input>`child of that same `<tr>` which has an attribute `type`
> with an attribute value of `checkbox`.

Now you let `document.evaluate()` evaluate it, and once that element is found, have javascript toggle that element's `checked` status.

All together:

```
xpath = '//table//tr[.//.="Company 2"][.//.="Product type 1"]//input[@type="checkbox"]';
target = document.evaluate(
  xpath,
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
);

target.singleNodeValue.checked = true;
```